# Generating random sparse data in the range 0-1

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to generate sparse 3 dimensional nonparametric datasets in the range 0-1, where the dataset should contain zeros as well. I tried to generate this using:

```
training_matrix = numpy.random.rand(3000, 3)
```

but it is not printing the data as 0.00000 in any of the rows.

Comment: What shape should be your array?

Comment: array should be 3000 rows with 3 columns where some rows should be like,   0.00000  0.00000 0.00000  0

Comment: 3000 rows by 3 cols corresponds to a 2D array rather than a 3D array

Comment: @Tonechas, it seems that OP is modeling a 3D dataset with a 2D array by having each dimension be a column in a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by creating an array of zeros of `nrows` rows by `3` columns:

```
import numpy as np
nrows = 3000   # total number of rows
training_matrix = np.zeros((nrows, 3))
```

Then we randomly draw (without replacement) `nz` integers from `range(nrows)`. These numbers are the indices of the rows with nonzero data. The sparsity of `training_matrix` is determined by `nz`. You can adjust its value to fit your needs (in this example sparsity is set to 50%):

```
nz = 1500   # number of rows with nonzero data
indices = np.random.choice(nrows, nz, replace=False)
```

And finally, we populate the selected rows with random numbers through [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
training_matrix[indices, :] = np.random.rand(nz, 3)
```

This is what you get by running the code above:

```
>>> print(training_matrix)
[[ 0.96088615  0.81550102  0.21647398]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55381338  0.66734065  0.66437689]
 ..., 
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.03182902  0.85349965  0.54315029]
 [ 0.71628805  0.2242126   0.02481218]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want all 5 numbers to be zero, the probability of that occurring is 1/10^5 = 0.00001, with replacement. The probability of getting that is still negligible, even if you have 3000*3=9000 values. Something else you can try doing for your peace of mind is to generate random numbers and truncate them at a certain point, ie 5 decimal places if you want.